# There is a poem hidden in this puzzle. Can you solve it?

Tags: cipher

Гӓд ӓв aӱӑ фɑҙӑз, нӑӱн ӓв ӑӱлд,

```
Лӧд ӑӱвӑр aӱӑ фɑфләң хйuмӑн рёс,
```

Бӥнiҫ хuз iтɜнл лӧ в̈i хӑӱлд

```
Дӑмӥнйӑн ӑӱвӑ ләнд әнд спёс -
```

Лӧд гӓд ӓв нёшӑнз, йuнaӥт әс йɛт,

```
Бaӥ ҙaӥ лӧ, ҙi ессене мӓрӑл ёбiсi ӓв ҙӑ фрi
```

Лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт - лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт!

Фɑ-кӧлд aӱӑ нёвiз мɛлт ӑв̈ё,

```
Ӓн дйuн әнд хɛдлӑнд сӥңкс ҙӑ фaӥӑ:
```

Гӓн ӥз ӧл aӱӑ пӓмп ӓв йɛстӑдё,

```
Гӓн в̈ӥҙ нӥнӥвӑ әнд тaӥӑ.
```

Лӧд гӓд ӓв нёшӑнз, йuнaӥт әс йɛт,

```
Бaӥ ҙaӥ лӧ, ҙӑ мӓрӑл ёбiсi ӓв ҙӑ фрi
```

Лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт - лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт!

Ҙӑ тйuмәлт әнд ҙӑ шaӱтӥң дaӥз:

```
Ҙӑ кәптӥнз әнд ҙӑ кӥңз дӥпɑт:
```

Стӥл стәндз йӧр ёншӑнт сәкрӥфaӥс,

```
Ӑ хәмбл әнд ӑ кӑрёʤӑс хɑт.
```

Лӧд гӓд ӓв нёшӑнз, йuнaӥт әс йɛт,

```
бaӥ ҙaӥ лӧ, ҙӑ мӓрӑл ёбiсi ӓв ҙӑ фрi
```

Лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт - лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт!

Ӥф, дрәңк в̈ӥҙ сaӥт ӓв пaӱӑ, в̈i шӱд лuс,

```
Вaӥлд тәңз ҙәт хәв нӓт йu ӥн ӧ,
```

Сәʧ бӑӱстӥңз әз смӧл ʧӥлдрӑн йuз,

```
Ӧ гӓдлӥс бiстс ˌaӱтсaӥд ҙaӥ лӧ!
```

Лӧд гӓд ӓв нёшӑнз, йuнaӥт әс йɛт,

```
Бaӥ ҙaӥ лӧ, ҙӑ мӓрӑл ɛсiн ӓв ҙӑ фрi
```

Лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт - лɛст в̈i фӑгɛт!

Фӧ фuлӥш хɑт ҙәт пӱтс ӥтс трәст

```
Ӥн мәнмёд тйuб әнд aӥӑн шɑп,
```

Ӧл пɑсӥң дәст ҙәт бӥлдз ӓн дәст,

```
Әнд гɑдӥң ӥт, кӧлз нӓт йu тu гɑд.
```

Фӧ фрәнтӥк бӑӱст әнд фuлӥш в̈ɜд -

```
Хәв мɜсi ӓн ҙaӥ пiпл, лӧд!
```

Ӑ мән әнд нӓт ӑ мәңкi, ӑ мән! ɑмɛн.

Hint 1:

> This is an English cypher.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! You don't need to give a hint immediately with the question - most people generally hold off on those until a day or two after the puzzle is shared.

Comment: In this case, though, it helps to know the language intended for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be

> a rough phonetic substitution cipher of English, using Cyrillic letters for their phonetic values where possible (and what appear to be a few regular IPA letters).

The poem is

> "God Our Eternal Father", from Dr. Bronner's Magic Soaps: an adaptation of Rudyard Kipling's [Recessional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recessional_(poem)). It appears to be printed on some of their soap bottles; a PDF of one of the labels can be found [here](https://www.drbronner.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bronner-US-liquid-32oz-lavender-LSLA32US8-02.pdf), with the text of the poem in the upper left.
>
>   The full text of the poem is:
>
> ```
> God of our fathers, known of old,
> Lord over our far-flung human race,
> Beneath whose eternal law we hold
> Dominion over land and space -
> Lord God of nations, unite us yet,
> By thy law, the Essene Moral ABC of the free
> Lest we forget - lest we forget!
> Far-called our navies melt away,
> On dune and headland sinks the fire:
> Gone is all our pomp of yesterday,
> Gone with Nineveh and Tyre.
> Lord God of nations, unite us yet,
> By thy law, the Moral ABC of the free
> Lest we forget - lest we forget!
> The tumult and the shouting dies:
> The captains and the kings depart:
> Still stands your ancient sacrifice,
> A humble and a courageous heart.
> Lord God of nations, unite us yet,
> By thy law, the Moral ABC of the free
> Lest we forget - lest we forget!
> If, drunk with sight of power, we should loose,
> Wild tongues that have not you in awe,
> Such boastings as small children use,
> Or Godless beasts outside thy law!
> Lord God of nations, unite us yet,
> By thy law, the Moral ABC of the free
> Lest we forget - lest we forget!
> For foolish heart that puts its trust
> In manmade tube and iron sharp,
> All passing dust that builds on dust,
> And guarding it, calls not You to guard.
> For frantic boast and foolish word -
> Have mercy on thy People, Lord!
> A man and not a monkey, a man! Amen.
> ```

Comment: Great! Do you speak a Cyrillic language? I chose that poem because it’s not well known.

Comment: @Galactic No, I don't, but I know the script decently well. (Enough to get the consonants you used translated, along with a few vowels, and then figure out enough of the words to find the poem.)